# How to create Progress bar in Qt4?

Tags: progress-bar, vlc, qt4.8, qprogressbar

I tried to create a progress bar using below sequence of code, but showed me an error, which is

> incomplete type is not allowed

.

The code snippet is as follows:-

```
QProgressBar *bar;

bar= new QProgressBar(0);//error: incomplete type is not allowed at QProgressBar
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use `#include <QProgressBar>`.

If you use a forward declaration for `QProgressBar`, you can include its header in your cpp file.